# Custom link open to anchor tab in page

Tags: wordpress, tabs, anchor

I am wanting to create Custom Links within my menu to open to (open) tabs on a page. I have tried to use anchors but this is not working.

Please see example for URL: https://adventurethon.savvylittlefreelancer.com/

Main menu > Events (dropdown) > Clarence Valley > Results
Under main menu settings, I have created a Custom Link for "Results" and want this to redirect straight to the Results Tab under Event > Clarence Valley when clicked on.

I have given a section within the tab an ID or clarence-results and linked this to Menu Custom Link > Anchor = #clarence-results with no luck.
[Anchor ID on Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wovWd.png)
[Anchor ID in Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O79ji.png)

I have also added in the direct URL: https://adventurethon.savvylittlefreelancer.com/event/clarence-valley-nsw/#clarence-results & adventurethon.savvylittlefreelancer.com/event/clarence-valley-nsw/#clarence-results (with no https://)
And no luck.

The custom links direct to page successfully but does not take me to the "results" part of the page. 
Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because a parent element of the tag with the "clarence-results" ID is being hidden with CSS `display: none`. Make sure the element is showing, and the jump link should work.

[image: The parent element that is being hidden is highlighted blue. You can see the inline style that is declaring "display: none;"]

I have checked and there is not reliable way to select this particular element with CSS. I suspect it is being hidden by some sort of setting in the backend, so your options are:

- Find the setting that makes this element visible
- Add a visible element above it with an ID, and use that as the anchor. If you don't want it to be visible, you could use `visibility: hidden` and/or `height: 0; overflow: hidden;`
- Add an ID to the wrapping column or row, then use that as the anchor.

Without being able to see your site's admin, it's difficult to find the best way to fix it. But the root of the problem is that the ID you are linking to is not visible on the page, so you need to either make it visible (I strongly suspect there is a setting somewhere that is hiding it), or you need to link to a different (visible) ID.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the parent element is that is displaying as none, but I tried to

```css
#clarence-results {
display: inline;
}
```

Not quite sure how to display the parent element.

Thanks!